# How do you terminate another user's session in Vaadin such as when you fire someone?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

I understand that I can do:

```
getPage().setLocation("/myapp/logout.html");
VaadinSession.getCurrent().close();
```

on a logout button, etc. But if I'm managing the users under my account and I terminate a user because they were fired how can I force their session(s) to be immediately terminated?

Comment: Maybe, if you implement your UI with @Push you could make the UI invalidate its session by itself from server command? At the same time you could show error notification "You're fired".

Comment: You can check access rights during every request and let filter to close session if needed.

Comment: Here's documentation for vaadin request handlers https://vaadin.com/docs/framework/advanced/advanced-requesthandler.html